# Get the count of services every username gets

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have this table :

```
    serviceID    Name     L_name    
  --------------------------------
        1         A         B      
        2         A         B
        3         C         D
        4         E         F
```

and i want to get the count of services every person gets :

```
         Name    L_Name    Countf
   ---------------------------------
          A         B        2
          C         D        1
          E         F        1
```

this is a query i wrote and doesn't have the right resultset:

```
select * 
from  
(Select  Name,L_Name,COUNT(Service_ID) as 'countf' 
from Service_Tbl  
group by Name,L_Name) as tbl
```

i get this :

```
         Name    L_Name    Countf
   ---------------------------------
          A         B        1
          A         B        1
          C         D        1
          E         F        1
```

Comment: Where does that Date column come from in your group by?

Comment: oh that's nothing. i forgot to erase that.

Comment: Do you get an error? If not; what's wrong with the resultset? I'm not experienced with sql-server, but in MySQL the inner query as it is now should give you the correct result...

Comment: No i don't get error, edited the question.

Comment: And if you just run the inner query?

Comment: I just constructed a table in SQL 2008 to match yours and ran your **inner** query and it gave the exact result you wanted.  Are you sure that you aren't excluding other important information about this table/query?

Comment: then i cant use where statement on "countf" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group` your results like this:

```
select Name, L_Name, COUNT(Service_ID) as 'countf'
from Service_Tbl  
group by Name,L_Name
```

Here it is a full example that gives the needed result:

```
create table #Service_Tbl  (
serviceID    int,
Name     varchar(1),
L_name    varchar(1)
)

insert into #Service_Tbl values (1, 'A','B')
insert into #Service_Tbl values (2, 'A','B')
insert into #Service_Tbl values (3, 'C','D')
insert into #Service_Tbl values (4, 'E','F')

select Name, L_Name, COUNT(ServiceID) as 'countf'
from #Service_Tbl  
group by Name,L_Name

drop table #Service_Tbl
```

Comment: Isn't that just an exact copy of the OP's inner query?!

Comment: I agree - I have commented on his question that maybe he isn't giving us the full story!

Comment: i can't use where statement on "countf" field.